# .NET simple application update mechanism

Tags: .net, deployment, visual-studio-2005, installation, windows-installer

Environment:

- .NET
- C#
- [Visual Studio 2005](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2005) and
- Some third-party components
- .vdproj files (setup projects inside Visual Studio 2005) for .msi building - not "[ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) deployment"

*Problem*

I am in a project phase where there are several updates to the project during a day. Since every change is small (two assemblies at most), it would be convenient for the user to use some kind of automatic update that will be both fast and worry-free.

*Proposition*

I would like to do a simple system that would store my application files somewhere on my server, along with some XML file that will list them with their hashes. A desktop application will read XML, compare hashes, download the required files, restart the application and the user would have a new version without even noticing it.

So my thoughts go further...

Client application for it: simple, day or two of work. Considerations:

- Have to take care of permissions to write files to user program directory (actually I'm helpless if I can't)
- Have to launch an updater process that will download and replace files and relaunch the original application
- Have to make a local XML file with hashes at the first run, and for that I need local list of deployed files that could change (since all of them aren't just in the local application folder)

Server side is trivial, but there are also some considerations:

- The root file with current version description, file list and hashes
- Manually upload files to server, create tool for hashing files

Is there some tool that follows my train of thought to do that without much hassle from the side?

Comment: Hm, it seems that every options mentioned below has a problem: COM files aren't mentioned at all, and I haven't found any option of specifying target directory for the file.  Curious...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some solutions:

[Updater Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978574.aspx) - [instructions](http://www.theserverside.net/tt/articles/showarticle.tss?id=UpdateAppBlock) on how to use it

[.NET Client Applications: .NET Application Updater Component](http://windowsclient.net/articles/appupdater.aspx)

[Appupdater](http://www.nabber.org/projects/appupdater/)

Answer (score 4):

What you describe sounds a lot like **ClickOnce**. Yes: I noticed that your wrote that the application is installed via MSI, and that's fine.

ClickOnce is more than just initial installation. There are many options, and you [can set it up so that it checks for updates even if the application is already running](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s22azw1e.aspx), and there's also an API that you can use if the declarative approach isn't flexible enough for you.

Comment: agree: it sounds like mosmondor is rewriting clickonce. Is there a feature of MSI that you're depending on that can't be replicated in clickonce?

Comment: I was a bit cautious around ClickOnce but I have to say it works as advertised and is really straight forward to set up.

Comment: There was something that averted me from using ClickOnce.  I had a feeling that it's a great idea, but wasn't polished and will be abandoned like some M$ inventions...

Comment: @mosmondor: I have no idea if what you say is true or not, but even *if* it's true, 'abandonment' in the .NET framework means that it will not be further developed - there will still be 10 years support on it. I don't know what you are capable of, but I'm pretty certain ClickOnce is better and more robust than anything I could develop singlehandedly in a week or two :)

Comment: @mark: any code that is developed is worth using.  Years of developing taught me so.  Even if code is from Microsoft :)